# gRPC metada returned from server only available when C# client uses async calls?

Tags: async-await, metadata, grpc

I'm experimenting with gRPC as a possible technology to use. I've written a synchronous client and server in c++. The server returns metadata to the client and the client can successfully access the metadata.

I'm now testing a c# client with the same c++ synchronous server. It appears that to get access to metadata returned by the server, the client must use an async call to the server. I can't get that to work, so I'm wondering:

1. Should it work?
2. Is there a way to get metada without using the async version of calls from the client?

Since my test can't get this working, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong. I've got a method that looks like the code below. When a client calls a 'Connect' method I want the server to generate a unique key and send it back. From that point on the client sends that key in metadata so the server can determine which client is calling.

Here's my attempt. The "ItemInterface.Items.ItemsClient client" parameter passed to the method is an instance of the class generated by protoc:

```
private static async Task<string> _MakeConnection(ItemInterface.Items.ItemsClient client, ItemInterface.ConnectRequest request)
{
    string serverAssignedKey = "";
    CallOptions options = new CallOptions();

    var answer = client.ConnectAsync(request, options);
    var response = await answer.ResponseAsync;
    serverAssignedKey = answer.GetTrailers().First(e => e.Key == "client_id").Value;

    return serverAssignedKey;
}
```

The call makes it to the server and leaves the server, but then never returns back to my calling method. The client is hung.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ken, do you have an example of how you're making the call synchronously? The code you've posted looks like the async example?

Comment: [Don't block on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @Stephen - you're exactly right. Thank for pointing that out. Is there a way to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: I was on my phone so I couldn't type up a full answer then. Just wanted to get you unblocked quickly with a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm now testing a c# client with the same c++ synchronous server. It appears that to get access to metadata returned by the server, the client must use an async call to the server.

When dealing with any kind of network communication (including gRPC), the synchrony and asynchrony of the server is completely independent from the synchrony and asynchrony of the client. The fact that the server is synchronous does not have any effect on the client; it may be synchronous or asynchronous regardless of the server implementation.

> The call makes it to the server and leaves the server, but then never returns back to my calling method. The client is hung.

Here's the part that provides the clue: when an asynchronous call hangs, it is most likely due to a [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) because that code has been blocked on somewhere further up the call stack. More specifically, `await` in C# captures a "context" by default. One common scenario is GUI applications, which have a UI context, which only runs on the UI thread. If the code blocks the UI thread by waiting on this task to complete, then when the `await` is ready to resume the method, it can't because the UI thread is blocked.

The best solution is to not block on asynchronous code - i.e., use ["async all the way"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). There are [alternatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), but they're much more risky.